# Accessing variables in local environment in R

Tags: r, global-variables, environment

I am reading Hadley Wickham's Advanced R to understand this language in a better way. I came across a section in the chapter Environments where he talks about the preference given to local variable over global variable.

For instance,

```
h <- function(){
  x<-10
  function(){
    x
  }
}
i<-h()
x<-20
i()
```

This could would return `10` and not `20` because local `x` overrides global `x`.

However, when I applied similar logic to the below code, global variable `y` overrode local `y`.

```
x <- 0
y <- 10
f <- function() {

  x <- 1
  g()
}
g <- function() {
  x <- 2
  y<-5 #Added by me
  h()
}
h <- function() {
  x <- 3
  x + y
}
f()
```

The output is `13`. I would have expected `8` because I have created a local variable `y` in `h()`'s calling function `g()`. Isn't it?

I'd appreciate any comments and guidance.

Answer (score 0):

When the `h()` function is called you assign `x` to 3 which is local to that function. When it tries to evaluate `x + y` it doesn't find the definition of `y` in local function hence, it takes the value of `y` which is declared globally i.e 10. Hence, the output is 10 + 3 = 13. The value of `y` in `g()` function is local only to that function and not to `h()` function. The local environment of all the functions is different and independent of one another.

If you want `y` to maintain it's value from the `g` function you can pass the value of `y` in the `h()` function.

Update the two functions like this :

```
g <- function() {
     x <- 2
     y<-5 
     h(y)
}

h <- function(y) {
    x <- 3
    x + y
}
```

So now when you call the `f()` function you get output as expected

```
f()
#[1] 8
```

Also, if you update your `y` in your `g()` function to

```
g <- function() {
      x <- 2
      y <<-5 #Note the <<- operator. 
     h()  
}
```

What `<<-` does is it updates the value of `y` in the global environment. So the value of `y` which was 10 before in the global environment is now changed to 5. Hence, when you call `f()` now, you will get output as 8 and not 13.